# Roku Debugging?

Tags: debugging, roku, brightscript

I do have Roku Express. I really dont know where to start with developing.
I have found where i can learn BrightScript used to build apps for ROKU.
([BrightScript Tutorial](https://codingalien.com/brightscript-a-detailed-introduction/))
That is not an issue - but big question is where i can debug such as "channel".

Is there a way that i can use notepad++ and telnet for debugging purposes?
I have found notepad++ highlighter here: [NOTEPAD++ BRIGHTSCRIPT HIGHLIGHTER](https://gist.github.com/triple-j/db8d76ede94ffdae9096a54fe8a1e0f1)

But i can not find eighter on google or here on stackoverflow how can i debug my application without playing with code and do trial/error, uninstalling, editing, zipping and sending it back to roku for testing.

Thanks for looking and hopefully some one know solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with Eclipse! Check the link out: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/4265458. 
You can use brihhtscript plug in for the Eclipse that will allow you to edit code, deploy it, debug... You can also use Atom with Roku dev package. You can debug using telent from terminal as well. Check your Roku local IP, open your terminal and type telnet 192.168.1.20(your ip address) 8085.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, Eclipse itself is "heavy stuff" but does have all of that what I need so far.

Comment: I am glad I could help. I now use ATOM but before was using Eclipse. Switched to ATOM because I wanted to use the sam IDE as rest of developers in the team. Eclipse is heavy but it has everything You need. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Eclipse for Roku debugging, there is no hidden magic in it.

All you have to do is side-load the ZIP, `telnet <roku-IP> 8085` and then either:

1. interrupt the app with ctrl-C, or
2. have breakpoint placed in the app via the `STOP` statement

When execution breaks into debugger, you can type commands directly - check/modify variables, call functions and so on. When finished, resume program execution by typing `c` and hit Enter

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent open source tool for Roku Debugging called [VioletBug](https://github.com/belltown/violetbug) that I would highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Roku Debugging is very easy with the help of the Visual Studio Code. It provides us a way to debug the code with the help of User Interface. Also, it automatically connects you with Roku with the help of telnet and we can use the debug console provided in VSC to print runtime variables and debug code.

More Details - [Roku Debugging - VSC](https://nativedevs.blogspot.com/2020/07/roku-series-debugging-in-roku-made-easy.html)